# To call in jquery using namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using javascript file and jquery.From my javascript file,I am doing like this:

```
abc.cde.on({

});
```

which is calling one widget written in jquery.

`abc.cde` are namespaces in jquery widget file.

Can anyone please tell how `abc.cde.on` is calling jquery method without using `$` sign before `abc.cde`

Answer (score 1):

Because `cde` is already an instance of a jQuery object. You can perfectly store the result of a jQuery selection (or a jQuery widget instance) in an object to reuse it after, see example:

```js
var namespace = {
  obj: $('div'),
};

//then you can do:
namespace.obj.on('click', function(){
  this.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the $ is already used in previous reference... I suspect abc was defined something like this:

```
var abc = $('#abc')
```

So the $ is already referenced...